# Node.js & Express.js/Jade res.render returns res.render is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I haven't been able to find an answer to this error as of yet and am wondering if it has to do with version 4 of Express

**controller.js**

```
var request = require('request');

var apiOptions = {
    server : "http://localhost:3000"
};
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    apiOptions.server = "https://heroku_path";
}



module.exports.homelist = function(req, res) {
    var requestOptions, path;
    path = '/api/locations';
    requestOptions = {
        url: apiOptions.server + path,
        method: "GET",
        json: {},
        qs : {
            lng : -117.929835,
            lat : 33.614675,
            max : 30000
        }
    };
    request(requestOptions, function(err, res, body) {
        renderHomepage(req, res, body);
});    

var renderHomepage = function(req, res, body) {
    res.render('jade-template', {
        title: 'I'm a main title',
        pageHeader: {
            title: 'I'm a title',
            strapline: 'I'm a strapline'
        },
        locations: body,
        sidebar: 'yadda yadda'
    });
};
```

The homelist function gets called from my routes.js which is then where my API gets called from my request with the query found in requestOptions.

however when the request callback is fired and renderHomepage in invoked with the API variable body I get the error:

```
res.render('jade-template', {
     ^
TypeError: res.render is not a function
```

All my routes are set up and tested fine. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `res` argument in the `renderHomepage` function (the `request`'s callback) is not the same as the `res` of the express route!

Change your call the `request` to something like:

```
request(requestOptions, function(err, serverRes, body) {
    renderHomepage(req, res, body);
});
```

Then the response to your `request` to `/api/locations` is `serverRes`, and the response you send to your client is `res`.

Comment: This was it! Thank you.